# What was wrong with my link answers?

Tags: discussion

I truly hate to have to ask this, but is it a sport to flame newbies here?

I answered 2 questions today with almost no answers about alchemy in Skyrim with a link to an APP that allows users to enter any and all ingrediants and then submit it to see what if anything can be made of them.

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/41952/23

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/41951/23

This I thought was uber useful and made no attempt to do anything other that truly offer an APP that has helped me greatly. Not less that 45 mins after I'm flamed by 3 people on 1 and 2 on another and then unable to answer another being sent to the why am i seeing this: you're banned link... o_0

Thankfully some others actually checked the link and responded favorably and so i can respond again.

Do people on this site flame first and read links later? I truly ask cause if this is the case i will never offer one of my useful tools in an attempt to share the Skyrim LOVE.

This caught me so off guard with all that I had read about this site and its rules
and FAQs.

Thank you in advance for your time and comments

Comment: Did you actually try to answer the question, or was it just, "<link>" ? Which answers are you referring to specifically?

Comment: You've been, uh, banned? I'm checking your account and I can't find anything about it.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I've put a link to the answers _I THINK_ he's referring to. They've accumulated offensive flags fairly quickly.

Comment: The one answer with -6 should be a comment instead.  It's useful and related but doesn't answer the question.  Obviously I can't speak to any deleted answers (with or without flaming/banning).

Comment: i didn't include the LINKS so as to not offend anyone who might have thought i was somehow self promoting...

Comment: after i got the 8 flames,which i was unaware of at the time,

Comment: i recieved this link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi/86998#86998

Comment: Okay, so here's your first problem: Getting down votes does not mean you're getting "flamed". It means that either people didn't find your post helpful, they thought it was spam (and to be fair, you *were* posting identical answers in a few threads), or thought it could use some explanation to go with a link. None of them meant to insult you personally, they just want you to give some more context when you post an answer.

Comment: yeah there were 2 alchemy questions that i thought could use the same tool since i hadn't seen one like it listed i was just trying to share : ) i didn't take it personally was just very surprised cause like i said after the 8 i got the link listed above. in the future if i do decide to share a personal link i find useful which isn't often i will be sure to be overly detailed,thanks

Comment: lol now 1 of the posts has come back from minus back to 0 but the other is just getting auto flamed cause people see the earlier ones so seems like there are more than a few Shoot first know what their talking about later members on here, oh and not 1 comment on either of them about a spam link or whatever,hope you all don't treat your neiborhood kids like this...shoot first ask questions later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I can't say that it's a sport to flame anyone.  I didn't flag or downvote either of the answers that were added to your question, but I can speculate that there's a couple of things that probably tripped other folks' radars:

- The answers look like spam.  They're a bare link with some text added, posted very close together in time.  This is a pattern that you see pretty frequently when a site gets hit by some type of spam attack/bot.
- There was some suspicion that perhaps your intent was to promote something that you benefit from, which happens from time to time and is actually part of [the FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).
- They don't answer the question, although they are good partial resources for doing so.  Things posted as answers that don't do a complete job of answering the question tend to get voted down (or not voted up, which is kind of my preference).
- Posting just a link to something is considered to be less desirable than answering the question in the answer, because sometimes things on the internet move or go down, and we'd like the site to be a place where people can come to find answers far into the future.

I know this wasn't your intent.  I'm sorry you had a bad experience because of the way your answers matched a pattern that is frequently used by abusive users of the system.

A more complete answer, or perhaps some better editing would probably have avoided all of these issues.  Someone came along after you and tried to improve the answers you left to the best of their ability.

If you just want to post something quick that only partially answers a question with a useful resource, consider a comment.  They're more suited to giving that sort of feedback to a question asker.

Getting used to the way this system works can be tricky, but it's really quite a bit of fun to help people with their issues.  I'm glad you've chosen to come here and try to figure out what went wrong, and I hope that you'll continue to contribute to the site in the future.

Comment: thank you, i only supplied the Link cause i hadn't seen one like it listed anywhere so i wanted to share the Love with it's resources,cause it's an instant answer response to ingrediants. in the future i'll add more details,my other responses had been long and i was worried That would put some people off : )

Comment: Nope, so far nobody's given me any grief for long winded answers.  Thanks for understanding. :)